# A statement for flat modules analogous to the Baer's Criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, flatness

Recently I came across the following statement about the criterion of flat modules which looks somewhat like Baer's Criterion for injective modules:

**Statement**. Let $R$ be a commutative ring. An $R$-module $M$ is flat if and only if for every ideal $I\subset R$ the canonical map $I\otimes_{R} M \rightarrow M, \; r\otimes m \mapsto rm$ is an injective $R$-homomorphism.

We use the definition of flatness: an $R$-module $M$ is called a flat module if the functor $- \otimes_R M$ is an exact functor.

I think this is true, and one direction is obvious by the definition. But I have no idea how to prove (or disprove) the other direction.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For the OP, this proposition is also in most commutative algebra books: see Matsumura's  *Commutative Algebra*, chapter 2 section 3, or Bourbaki's *Commutative Algebra*, chapter 1.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you! But I don't know whether this is a nontrivial statement?

Comment: What does that matter? The proof of this statement is one of the first things you see when you read about flatness in many texts, and the proof isn't nothing but it's not super complicated either.